# Adding Loop cuts distorts Mesh

Tags: modeling

I've made a smooth curve on my model,(subsurface modifier is applied) But when I add more loop cuts on the top side of my mesh, the smooth circle gets distorted. I want to be able to add details where the curve is without distorting the initial curve. I tried moving the vertices around, but the curve becomes jagged and messy. Is there a way to achieve adding more geometry without tampering the curve?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: For what purpose do you need more geometry?If its just more geometry you can simple apply the subsurf modifier at some lower level.

Comment: I wan to add UI elements. Such as knobs and sliders.

https://ibb.co/3ChVrVF